# Organizing minitest integration tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, minitest

So I'm using Minitest to do integration tests. I would like to have some rspec-like context function, so I divided my tests into different files. Since I want to test EventsController, all my files started as this:

```
class EventsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
```

when I try to run a directory of file, the `setup` methods of these classes were overwritten since they are all redefining the same class and I couldn't have the methods in different files with the same name. What's the proper way to split all these tests? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found it in the docs. Name the test class differently, and use `tests EventsController` to manually set the target controller.